# Inserting random element from JavaScript array in html string

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have an array of strings:

```
var prepositions = ['on', 'in', 'under', 'behind', 'above']
```

And I want to insert a random element from this array into an html string at the gap shown:

```
"The yellow object is ____ the blue object"
```

More specifically, I want this sentence to appear as many times as there are words in the array, with a different one each time, in a random order.

I'm very new to JavaScript so not even sure where to start with this. Any ideas?

Comment: Which part are you having an issue with?  Getting a random index, or inserting a value into the string?  Those are two parts of your single problem.  You need to break the problem down into the basic steps and tackle them one at a time.

Comment: @Taplar I know how to select a random element from the array. I don't know to insert that value into the string.

Comment: So then you need to look up how to do string concatenation, or "template literals"

Answer (score 1):

This will create a copy of the array, then loop through the original array length and remove words from the copied array as they are used so that there won't be duplicates.

```js
function randomizePrepositions(sentence, prepositions) {
  words = prepositions.slice()
  out = "";
  for (z = 0; z < prepositions.length; z++) {
    pos = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)
    word = words[pos];
    out += sentence.replace("___",word)
    words.splice(pos, 1)
  }
  
  return out;
}

var prepositions = ['on', 'in', 'under', 'behind', 'above']

div = document.querySelector("div");
div.innerHTML = randomizePrepositions("The yellow object is ___ the blue object<br>", prepositions)
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how u do it:

```js
let prepositions = ['on', 'in', 'under', 'behind', 'above']

document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML = `The yellow object is ${prepositions[Math.floor(Math.random()*prepositions.length)]} the blue object`;
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <div id="output"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could shuffle your array first and afterwards pick one preposition after the other using the setNextSentence() function. The sentences are displayed for some time (e.g. 10 seconds) and switched automatically until the last sentence has been shown.

```
var prepositions = ['on', 'in', 'under', 'behind', 'above']
// assuming there is an html element like <span id="sentence"></span>
var elem = document.getElementById('sentence')
var active = 0
shuffle(prepositions)
// first sentence displayed immediately
setNextSentence()
// triggered by timer each 10 seconds
var timer = setInterval(setNextSentence, 10000)   

function setNextSentence() {
  elem.innerHTML = "The yellow object is " + prepositions[active] + " the blue object"
  active++
  if (active == prepositions.length) {
    // stop the timer
    clearInterval(timer)
  }
}

function shuffle(a) {
  let j, x, c;
  for (c = a.length; c; c--) {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * c);
    x = a[c - 1];
    a[c - 1] = a[j];
    a[j] = x;
  }
  return a;
}
```

Comment: You didn't include in your answer how `getNextSentence` would be used to get 5 sentences.

Comment: True - was not sure about the exact scenario. I have added two possible variants now to give an idea.

Comment: From the OP.  "More specifically, I want this sentence to appear as many times as there are words in the array, with a different one each time, in a random order."  There's no need for an interval.  You just loop the number of times there are elements in the array

Comment: Sure there is a need for an interval  - OP "with a different one each time"

Comment: This is starting to be fun. OP: There is quite some evolution to this answer - hope we will get it right in the end.

Comment: "each time" is easily assoicated with how many times the sentence is generated.  Nothing about that says you have to use an interval at all.

Comment: Thanks both. I don't necessarily need an interval, but otherwise I think this `setNextSentence` function works.

Comment: @shleen, my answer is cleaner and accomplishes what you are looking for plus it allows you to easily reuse the function for more than one sentence.